# Questions using Cloudera Quickstart 5.2.0 and Oozie

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I have some questions about using Hadoop and Hue in the Cloudera quickstart VM version 5.2.0.  The questions fit together.  I have not changed any configuration for any op the parts.

First, where are the save queries I make in Hive stored in HDFS?

Second, the default location of saved Hive queries, is that location visible to the Hue Oozie workflow editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command since they are in a database.

hue dumpdata beeswax.savedquery > your_file.json.

You can then reimport them.

But you will lose the ids of the queries ('pk') and users ('owner') I think.

You might be interested by this documentation if you are using HUE:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/Hue-2-User-Guide/hue27.html

Have a nice day :)